# Choosing a TTC Font in GD Library

Tags: php, gd

I am using the following to write a text over an image using the GD Library:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('myImage.jpg');
$black = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);
$font_path = 'myFont.ttc';
imagettftext($jpg_image, 20, 270, 712, 12, $black, $font_path, $text);      
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Now even though the function "imagettftext" clearly states it's a font of type "TTF", I am still able to use a font collection with the "TTC" extension as seen above and that will pick the first font in the collection by default. The only problem is that I cannot specify the index of the font style. As you know "TTC" is a collection of fonts under one file, like "Arial" can have "Regular", "Bold", "Italic", etc...

So I would like a way to also assign the index to choose the font style variant or style within the TTC file. Is there a way to do that with GD?

I would love this process to be automated (I don't want to convert my fonts online from TTC to individual TTF files because this will occur more than often and I would like to tool to be able to handle that). However, if the above is not possible, is there any library or function which I can use that breaks the TTC font to a collection of TTF fonts? This should do the job too.

Many thanks in advance.